# Authorization header malformed. (both in ajax call and curl )

Tags: php, basic-authentication

Hi I have this code that makes a Basic authorization and I get "Authorization header malformed" error:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "http://*******.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/10",
                type: "POST",               
                headers: { "Authorization": "Basic "+ btoa("***:****") },
                data: {"featured_media" : 12,"title":'q'},
                success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                },
                error:function(data){
                  console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

I have also tried with curl php  and I have the same error:

```
$process = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(["title"=>'tstttt']));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$return = curl_exec($process);
curl_close($process);
```

and tried placing the authorization in the header , but still the same error:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
                                                'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("****:****")));
```

Comment: `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' . $token` try this

Comment: how do I get the token? I have user and pass...

Comment: You have to create one. I just showed you a general way, you can pass anything there